Convert pdf files to jpeg using Google Cloud Functions + GraphicsMagick
I have set up GraphicsMagick running on a Google Cloud Function, and it works with no issues when converting files, such as converting PNG to JPEG.
I am aware of the issue regarding Adobe PDF/PS files, as by default, the GraphicsMagick policy configuration file is set to read-only for those file types.
To remediate this, I've set up MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH to point to a new policy file located under /tmp/policy.xml:
 <policymap>
   <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />
   <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="AI" />
   <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PS" />
 </policymap>

I pass the env variables, including MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH to GraphicsMagick when I run it (see exec(`convert... below).
However, I still get the error:
Error: Command failed: convert "/tmp/input.pdf" "/tmp/output.jpg"
convert-im6.q16: not authorized `/tmp/input.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412.

What am I missing in my GraphicsMagick configuration or setup?
See code of my GCF below:
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const busboy = require('busboy');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const exec = promisify(require('child_process').exec);

const tempPolicyPath = path.join('/tmp', 'policy.xml');
fs.writeFileSync(tempPolicyPath, `<policymap>
      <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />
      <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="AI" />
      <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PS" />
    </policymap>`);
process.env['MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH'] = tempPolicyPath;

const gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true });

interface UploadedFile {
  buffer: Buffer;
  name: string;
}
let loadedFile: UploadedFile;

const transform = async (res: Response, file: UploadedFile): Promise<any> => {
  const inPath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'input.pdf');
  const outPath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'output.jpg');
  await fs.promises.writeFile(inPath, file.buffer);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec(`convert "${inPath}" "${outPath}"`, {
      env: { ...process.env, MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH: tempPolicyPath },
    }).then(() => {
      const jpegData = fs.readFileSync(outPath);
      const jpegBase64 = jpegData.toString('base64');
      const jsonObj = {
        image: jpegBase64,
      }
      resolve({ code: 200, result: jsonObj });
    }).catch((err: any) => {
      reject({ code: 500, result: err });
    })
  });
}
exports.handler = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST');
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
    res.status(204).send('');
  } else {
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
      res.status(405).send('Method Not Allowed');
      return;
    }
    const bb = busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    let fileBuffer: Buffer = Buffer.alloc(0);
    bb.on('file', (fieldname: any, file: any, filename: any, encoding: any, mimetype: any) => {
      file.on('data', (data: any) => {
        fileBuffer = Buffer.concat([fileBuffer, data]);
      });
      file.on('end', () => {
        loadedFile = { buffer: fileBuffer, name: filename };
      });
    });
    bb.on('error', (error: any) => {
      logger.error('Busboy error:', error);
      res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    });
    bb.on('finish', () => {
      res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      transform(res, loadedFile)
        .then(({ code, result }) => {
          res.status(code).send(result);
        })
        .catch(({ code, result }) => {
          res.status(code).send(result);
        });
    });
    bb.end(req.body);
  }
}

